# Unable to read from the saved video in open cv in a loop

Tags: python, opencv, object-detection

I am fairly new to opencv and image editing, self learner you can say. I wanted have a poc of text morphing in videos like it happens with google lens but with the help of opencv.

I have achieved that for single video single run, but what I want to do is to take one input video, process it for the given positions of frames, save the output, then take that processed output as input for the next iteration and then save it after new edits are made.

I am trying to take data from a json file, which looks like this.

[JSON FILE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8d6FW.png)

Here is link to my code. I am a complete newbie trying to learn, so my methods and approch might be highly inefficient but I would appreciate any help.

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1WJVklMHESUAOa5wlLfjjpPVjOSfKt2i5?usp=sharing

Comment: and what's the exact error message?

Comment: There is no error. It just for some unknown reason doesn't read frames of that video if put in loop and just exit the loop. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: without error message it is diffucult for others to understand whats going on

Comment: please present a minimal reproducible example, then put it here in your question (edit it). https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you read the video till the end, it doesnt just reset.
so you need to reset the video on every loop. either open the videocapture again. move `cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_original)` inside your loop `for document in range`

or set the frame to whatever start frame (eg 0) you want using `cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, self.frame_num)` inside your loop

Comment: Thanks a lot. This was exactly what I was missing. Really, thank you very much